# Trying to use Connect-SPOService in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

This works fine locally but not when I try to run it in an Azure function.  I am assuming that I need to add it as a requirement in the requirements file as I have done with other modules?  I spent the last half hour searching but could not figure out how to it this for this particular module (I've done it with others).

**            Connect-SPOService -Url https://mycompany-admin.sharepoint.com -Credentials $cred
**

> > The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. >>

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to do something similar. I haven't tried yet. But maybe, like I do remotely, you have to import the module first, with Windows Compatabilty Mode, since it's a Core PowerShell?

```
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -UseWindowsPowerShell
```